# How can I use stronger typing in C by use of const type rather than #define?

Tags: c

I am trying to get away from using #define for constants to try and use the typing features of C, how would you recommend this is done?

```
const unsigned char THING_1 = 67;
const unsigned char THING_2 = 34;
```

but the following gives compiler errors saying that the initialisers aren't constant?!?!

```
static const unsigned char myArray[2] = {THING_1, THING_2};
```

How do I get around this?

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/m8XKdutaf4lzhgjm) after adding `=`. and `;`. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MikeCAT I believe compilers might decide differently what is a "compile-time" constant.

Comment: Very common FAQ. I thought we had a canonical dupe but I can't find it...

Comment: *the initialisers aren't const*  They aren't - they're variables.

Comment: @MikeCAT Umm... why _doesn't_ gcc or clang give a compiler error even in pedantic mode (`-std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`)? Beyond gcc 8.0 it stopped giving diagnostics, and clang never did, apparently.

Comment: @MikeCAT Try using a GCC version earlier than 8.  GCC seems to be slipping into the MSVC mode of merely paying poor lip service to C standard compliance...

Comment: I can't see an error either, even in -Wpedantic mode with GCC 8.3.0
Your code works and the array contains the expected values. It works as it should here.

Comment: It seems that ICC also used to throw an error but doesn't as of 17.0.0... ([16.0.3](https://godbolt.org/z/ddd8WPYrx), [17.0.0](https://godbolt.org/z/v3MhTsT93))

Comment: The thing is that there _should_ be a compiler error since variables are not integer constant expressions, even when `const`. Yeah it's stupid but that's the C standard. So all compilers decided to go non-compliant? C hasn't changed in this regard since C89.

Comment: Paul,  "gives compiler errors saying that the initialisers aren't const?!?!" --> I bet the error did **not** report _const_, but _constant_ (post true error message and true code).  `const` does not imply _constant_.

Comment: Tasking for AURIX... E306: initializer must be constant